# Is there a way to load data to HDFS from redshift?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-redshift

while loading to redshift, I used sqoop dfs to load data from HDFS to S3 and then with copy command, loaded data to redshift.

```
##
sqoop import -Dfs.s3.awsAccessKeyId= +awsAccessKeyId+ -Dfs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey= +awsSecretAccessKey+ -Dfs.s3.endpoint= +endpoint+ --connect  + jdbc_url +  --username= + user_id + --password= + decrypt_pwd +  --target-dir  + s3_path +
```

what is the way to bring back data from redshift to HDFS?

Comment: Please add more examples of what have you tried till now and why that did not work.

Comment: `sqoop export`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Unload data from Redshift to s3.
2. Use sqoop/distcp to copy data from s3 to hdfs.